# How to open a new window in Angular along with request json payload for POST request

Tags: javascript, html, angular, post

I have a button on the application (developed by angular 8). Once I clicked the button (perform a post request with some json payload and one new Url) that will take me to a new window in chrome. This is fine but, my json data is coming as form data which I don't want. I want to see my json in the request payload section in the developer tools.

This is my code.

```
public openNewWindow(valueObject: any) {
    const url = valueObject.url;
    const name = 'Test';
    const params = {id : 12345};
    const form = document.createElement('FORM');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
    form.setAttribute('action', url);
    form.setAttribute('target', name);
    for (const index in params) {
      if (params.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.name = index;
        input.value = params[index];
        form.appendChild(input);
      }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    window.open(url, name);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
  }
```

I am not getting where I am doing mistake and how to see the Json in the request payload in the Developers Tools of new window. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, the form is being appended to the main window. When you open your new window with window.open and pass valueObject.url that will open a totally new window that does not have any connections to the already created form.

Comment: Ok sir. what will you suggest now?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve?

 If for example:

The original window is on doman1, and your new window is on domain2, it is clear, that if you want to open a new window and perform some HTTP calls, it would be a big security issue, that's why it's impossible and forbidden ofc. (Ofc you cannot do that if those were the same domains as well).

Comment: So whatever I am seeing under the form data are fine?

Comment: Not sure whaat are you referring to?